# The spin of light

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, quantum-spin, polarization, chirality

The so-called spin is circular polarization of light,that is the electric field rotates in either direction normal to propagation

Is it known or is there any theory about how fast the field rotates? does it make a circle in a second or in the time the oscillation takes place (or even less)? In other word does a $10^{12}\,\mathrm{Hz}$ photon spins $100$ times less than a $10^{14}\,\mathrm{Hz}$ one? Is there an explanation why the 'spin' is always $1\cdot h$ for all frequencies?

EDIT

does the direction of the spin alternate as the field goes from plus to minus and viceversa?

Comment: This article answers your question: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_angular_momentum_of_light

Comment: I think you meant $\hbar$ rather than $h$. In MathJax $\hbar$ is \hbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct. Circular polarisation results from photon spin. This was experimentally proven by Beth in 1935. There is however a problem. Electromagnetic spin is incompatible with gauge invariance. This problem is usually not discussed in lectures and text books. An exception is Jackson, Electrodynamics, which touches on the topic in some problem in some advanced chapter (7.19).

If you want to know more read my peer reviewed paper on the subject. I opted to abandon gauge invariance for this very reason. I proved that this leads to a fully accurate and elegant theory of electromagnetism. See https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0106078. The work of Beth is in ref. 15.

As to you question the rotation frequency is equal to the oscillation frequency. All angular momentum is quantized in units of $\hbar$. The reason is unknown.

Comment: How can circular polarization result from photon spin when circular polarization exists classically and spin does not?

Comment: Does [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_angular_momentum_of_light) explain why the quantization is what it is?

Comment: The question did not ask about gauge invariance, yet this answer is mostly about that.

Comment: @G.Smith Circular polarization is a classical limit of a large number of photons with the same direction of spin. This fact explains how transverse waves are possible without a medium (aether). Spin and polarization are the same physics described by two different mathematical models, classical and quantum.

Comment: @safesphere Classical EM exists independently and does not have to be regarded merely as the classical limit of QED.

Comment: @G.Smith It doesn't have to be, but aren't you essentially asking how it is?

Comment: @G.Smith Both are mathematical models of the same reality. Each can be useful in its own way, but there is no denying that spin and polarization are the same physics. As a side note, personally I find that the classical model gives a deep insight missing in the quantum model. In this sense I agree that the classical model is not a mere classical limit of QED. In fact, as far as I am aware, there is no rigorous mathematical proof of this limit (or at least it is not trivial).

Comment: @AaronStevens I don’t think I’m asking that. I’m just trying to say that circular polarization exists in classical EM as something that has nothing to do with quantum mechanics, photons, or their spin, but, unless I am mistaken, is related to field angular momentum. By the way, I am sorry that you deleted your answer.

Comment: @G.Smith "*circular polarization exists in classical EM as something that has nothing to do with quantum mechanics, photons, or their spin*" - You can work with polarization in classical EM without referring to spin or QED, but if you refer, then circular polarization is always cased by photons with the same orientation of spin and cannot be constructed in any other way.

Comment: @safesphere OK, I think we agree.

Comment: Since I do agree that reality is in fact quantum mechanical, I can accept that “circular polarization results from photon spin” in that sense, even though when teaching classical EM I explained circular polarization in terms of field vectors without ever mentioning photons or spin.

Comment: thanks, so in visible light it spins 10^14 times a second?

Comment: In order of magnitude, yes. Actually 4.3 to 7.7 times that.